# It's possible to use validate-on-match and background-validation?

Tags: java, jboss

i want to know if it's possible to implement simultaneously:

```
<validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
<background-validation>true</background-validation>
```

This implementation generates a error?? i know this is typically not used in conjunction, but it's possible?

Comment: What exactly do you want to archive? A combination of client side and server side validation? What about [HTML5 Constraint Validation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation) and server sided validation by PHP? Both at the same time is a bad idea. Never trust user input from client side.

Comment: Hi, i need to use this in jboss

Comment: On my local environment this combination can be used without exceptions with wildfly 11. Ironically the only way to reestablish the connection is with validate-on-match set to true (which should be outdated). Did you investigated further on this?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can choose one of them.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sect-database_connection_validation